# Twitter OAuth2 - using WinRT

Tags: c#, twitter, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have the following code:

```
        var oAuthConsumerKey = key;
        var oAuthConsumerSecret = secret;
        var oAuthUri = new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token");

        // Do the Authenticate
        var authHeaderFormat = "Basic {0}";

        var authHeader = string.Format(authHeaderFormat,
            Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthConsumerKey) + ":" +
            Uri.EscapeDataString((oAuthConsumerSecret)))
        ));

        var postBody = "grant_type=client_credentials";
        //"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"

        var req = new HttpClient();
        req.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authHeader);

        var c = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postBody));
        IHttpContent content = new HttpStringContent(c, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await req.PostAsync(oAuthUri, content);

        IHttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

        using (responseContent)
        {
            var data = await responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The error I get at the line indicated above is this:

```
response.Content = {"errors":  [{"code":170,"label":"forbidden_missing_parameter","message":"Missing required parameter: grant_type"}]}
```

So, my question is: how do I specify the "grant type" parameter?

EDIT:

Following @Jon's suggestion below, I tried adding the grant_type to the constructor for 'content', but it made no difference.

Comment: From this page (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth) it looks like you put it in the body like this "grant_type=client_credentials".

Comment: Thanks - I had seen that.  My question was more about how that is done.

Comment: I believe you need to call the constructor like this: HttpStringContent("grant_type=client_credentials")

Comment: No.  That is, that may be the case, but on it's own, it didn't work.  I also thought it might need to be encoded as UTF8, but that didn't help either

Comment: I am surprised no one else has chimed in. The only other thing I can see missing is the header: "Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8". I think you had this in the body before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it for several other cloud services. I have never tried Twitter, but this should work as long as the authorization header is correct:

```
    async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetToken(string key, string secret)
    {
        var oAuthConsumerKey = key;
        var oAuthConsumerSecret = secret;
        var oAuthUri = new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token");

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var authHeader = string.Format("Basic {0}",
        Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthConsumerKey) + ":" +
        Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthConsumerSecret))));
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authHeader);

        HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token"));
        msg.Content = new StringContent("grant_type=client_credentials");
        msg.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(msg);
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Yes - many thanks, this works.  It did require some tweaking (which I'll post back here when I get chance).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the value with quotes?

```
var postBody = "grant_type=\"client_credentials\"";
```